# Question about CM fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a totally real number field of degree $n$. Let $K/F$ be a finite abelian extension with $G:=\textrm{Gal}(K/F)$. Let $\tau_i$ denote the complex conjugation corresponding to any complex place of $K$ above a place $\sigma_i$ of $F$. Let $G'$ denote the subgroup of $G$ generated by $\frac{\tau_i}{\tau_j}$ for $i, j=1, \ldots, n$.

Let $H$ be a CM field such that $F \subseteq H \subseteq K$. Can anybody explain why $G'$ fixes $H$?
I suspect this should follow easily using properties of CM fields but I would like to see an argument with some details, since I am unable to work this out by myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you assume only that

- $H$ is totally complex and $H/E$ is a quadratic extension with $E$ totally real
- $\sigma_i$ is an embedding $\overline{H}\to \Bbb{C}$, $\rho$ is the complex conjugaison and  $\tau_i=\sigma_i^{-1} \rho \sigma_i\in Aut(\overline{H})$

Then

- $\tau_i$ acts trivially on $E$ and $H/E$ is Galois so $\tau_i(H)=H,\tau_i|_H\in Gal(H/E)$
- $\rho$ acts non-trivially on $\sigma_i(H)$ so $\tau_i|_H$ acts non-trivially on $H$ and hence $\tau_i|_H$ is the unique non-trivial element of $Gal(H/E)$
- ie. $\tau_i|_H=\tau_j|_H$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I would just like to clarify that by definition $E$ is the fixed field of $\tau_i|_H$?

Comment: If you assume only that $H$ is totally complex and $H/E$ is a quadratic extension with $E$ totally real then $\tau_i$ acts trivially on $E$ and $H/E$ is Galois so $\tau_i(H)=H$, and $\tau_i$ acts non-trivially on $H$ so $[H:E]=[H:H^{\tau_i}]=2$ gives that $E=H^{\tau_i}$.

Comment: I have rewritten everything to clarify that we don't care of $K,F$.

Comment: Thank you very much!